# Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Is there any way that would allow me to call a class as a function. I'm looking to have the functionality below, where there's a `main` method within the class and that's the one I want to have the method execute.

```
class test {
  constructor () {
    return this.main
  }
  main () {
    return Promise.resolve('thomas')
  }
}

test().then(name => {
  console.log(name)
})
```

It seems my only other option would be to have a wrapper function like this.

```
class Test {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
  }
  main () {
    return Promise.resolve(this.name)
  }
}

let test = (name) => {
  return new Test(name).main()
}

test('thomas').then(name => {
  console.log(name)
})
```

Comment: You have to use the `new` keyword when using JS classes. I agree that the second option you have provided would be correct. (or don't use classes)

Comment: A class constructs an object. Your constructor would return another function, not an instance of the class. That doesn't make a lot of sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Maybe a static method on the class is what you are looking for?

Comment: @FelixKling I would like to create a complex function that has a lot of inner workings and calls references to itself using `this.methodName` rather than creating a ton of small functions. I only want to use that one `main` function. I understand that it's not the best use of a class, but I can have my cake and eat it too if I wrap it like above.

Comment: are you just testing promises? I'm not sure if vanilla es6 promises but the Q library has a `Q(somevalue)` if you're trying to test resolving a promise. so you could do `Q('Thomas').tap(console.log)` or then if you plan on manipulating the promise before returning it. either way a class is not what you're looking for this kind of design. just make a single function?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, you'd better place this as answer, not just a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm years late, but the solution I found was this:

```
// MyLib.js
class MyLib {
  constructor(selector){}
  someMethod(){}
  ...
}

export function MyFunction(selector){
  return new MyLib(selector)
}
```

Then I don't need to use `new`, I can simply do `MyFunction().someMethod()`

For example, I wrote a simple jQuery replacement using vanilla js and I literally replaced ~90+% of my jQuery syntax simply by changing `$` to `J` such as:

```
J().ready(function(){})
J().ajax(...).then((res)=>{}).catch((err)=>{}) // used axios here
J('.someClass').find('li').last()
J('header').css({display:'block'})
//etc
```

On a side note, I found it a little more challenging to globally expose it with webpack... but I'm a little new to webpack (outside of boilerplates) - so yea.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 24):

Use the `new` keyword when using classes in JavaScript. I had a similar problem until I added `new` before the class name.